# How to send PUSH request to server of another domain without access to the server files

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, httprequest, push

I am trying to create my own interface for the Montana State "Schedule of Classes," but there is no public API to request course information.

The form used to search for course is on [this page](https://atlas.montana.edu:9000/pls/bzagent/bzskcrse.PW_SelSchClass), and that form submits to [this page](https://atlas.montana.edu:9000/pls/bzagent/bzskcrse.PW_ListSchClassSimple). I'm trying to use node.js with the request module to send a PUSH request to the receiving page in order to then get the results of the search for my interface.

Here is the code where make the request:

```
var ops = {
    sel_subj: [ 'dummy', 'M' ],
    bl_online: "FALSE",
    sel_day: "dummy",
    term: "201470",
    sel_inst: "ANY",
    sel_online: "",
    sel_crse: "",
    begin_hh: "0",
    begin_mi: "0",
    end_hh: "0",
    end_mi: "0"
};

request.post(
    'https://atlas.montana.edu:9000/pls/bzagent/bzskcrse.PW_ListSchClassSimple', 
    function(err, res, body){
        console.log(body);
    }
).form(ops);
```

Here is some sample PHP output that I got from saving the exact form used on their site and `var_dump($_POST)`:

```
array(11) { 
    ["sel_subj"]=> string(1) "M" 
    ["bl_online"]=> string(5) "FALSE" 
    ["sel_day"]=> string(5) "dummy" 
    ["term"]=> string(6) "201470" 
    ["sel_inst"]=> string(3) "ANY" 
    ["sel_online"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["sel_crse"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["begin_hh"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["begin_mi"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["end_hh"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["end_mi"]=> string(1) "0" 
}
```

And all I get from the request I make with node.js is a 404 response. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Both links 404 i.e. are not accessible, do you normally login to the site to view the schedule of classes? Also it seems unusual the use of port 9000

Comment: @ioseph - no login is required to view the courses. The reason I'm getting the 404 is because the push request isn't correct, I think. 9000 is the correct port.